# the number of words with n letters from A,B,C without sequences AA,BB,CC

Tags: combinatorics

the number of words with n letters from A,B,C  without sequences AA,BB,CC why is it $a_n=2a_{n-1}$? I didn't see how it fitting the  restriction

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the last letter in a string corresponding to $a_{n-1}$ ($n \geq 2$) is exactly one of A or B or C, and let's assume It's A without loss of generality.
Since you can't have them repeat twice, you can either have one of B or C at the end of a string corresponding to $a_n$. So in total you will have:
$$a_n=2a_{n-1}$$
one for B  in the end, and one for C in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Directly:

First letter: 3 choices. Each other letter: 2 choices. Number of words of length N = product of the numbers of choices for each letter = $____$.

Recursively:

Word W of length N+1 = word U of length N + any letter which is not the last letter of U. Thus, two choices for the completion of U into W.